# UIScrollView "view" property

Tags: iphone, inheritance, uiscrollview

In the documentation, UIScrollView inherits from UIView.  If that is true, why doesn't UIScrollView have a view property?  As in

```
self.scrollView.view addSubview
```

I get the error that view is not a property of UIScrollView.  I thought if you inherit from a superclass you get those properties as well?  Sorry for the noob question...  Thanks.

Comment: `UIScrollView` inherits from `UIView` and not `UIViewController` which has the `view` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a subview to an UISCrollView you just have to do:

```
[self.scrollView addSubview:view];
```

Answer (score 1):

As it's inherited from `UIView` So  it's itself an `UIView`.

```
[myScrollView addSubview:myView];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is primarily because UIScrollView is itself a view.  So calling `self.scrollView.view` would be the same as calling `self.view.view` on a view controller